# Sharepoint 2010 is Missing Administration Search Function / Dependencies

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, windows-sbs

Microsoft Small Business Server 2011 
Sharepoint 2010

---

I have missing server side dependencies.
[image]
I click on the link to see what is going on and
[image]
After doing some research I find that if I go to the following pages it should correct its self:
SearchAdministration.aspx
SearchFarmDashboard.aspx

Problem is, the pages are not there.
[image]

Any ideas on how to work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this version does not have this feature so I disabled the warnings for it.